# Checking cmd line argument in bash script bypass the source statement

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I have an bash script "build.sh" like this:

```
# load Xilinx environment settings
source $XILINX/../settings32.sh

cp -r "../../../EDK/platform" "hw_platform"

if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
    cp $1/system.xml hw_platform/system.xml
fi

echo "Done"
```

Normally I run it as "./build.sh" and it execute the "source" statement to set environment variables correct. Sometimes I need to let the script to copy file from an alternative place, I run it as "./build.sh ~/alternative_path/"; My script check whether there is an cmd line argument by checking $# against 0.

When I do that, the "source" statement at the beginning of the script somehow get skipped, and build failed. I have put two "echo" before and after the "source", and I see echo statements get executed.

Currently I circumvent this issue by "source $XILINX/../settings32.sh; build.sh". However, please advise what I have done wrong in the script? Thanks.

Comment: How do you know the source statement is getting skipped?

Comment: I don't believe you. Put an echo statement in `settings32.sh`, I'll bet it will execute. My guess is that `settings32.sh` is checking `$#` and not setting the variables you need.

Comment: Put `set -x` before the `source` line, this will show all commands as they're executed. This may help you understand where things are going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try storing the values of your positional paramaters first on an array variable then reset them to 0. `"$XILINX/../settings32.sh"` may be acting differently when it detects some arguments.

```
# Store arguments.
ARGS=("$@")

# Reset to 0 arguments.
set --

# load Xilinx environment settings
source "$XILINX/../settings32.sh"

cp -r "../../../EDK/platform" "hw_platform"

if [[ ${#ARGS[@]} -ne 0 ]]; then
    cp "${ARGS[0]}/system.xml" hw_platform/system.xml
fi

echo "Done"
```

Comment: Thanks that works, it's actually because the code in setting32.sh causing the problem!